# Starting at what version of Visual Studio is vsnprintf mostly standard-conformant?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, printf, standards

According to [Microsoft's documentation for `vsnprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx), that function is part of the C(++) Run-Time Library since at least the 2003 edition of Visual Studio.

```
int vsnprintf( char *buffer,        // Storage location for output
               size_t count,        // Maximum number of characters to write
               const char *format,  // Format specification
               va_list argptr )     // Pointer to list of other arguments
```

I'm asking: for which versions of Visual Studio is the `vsnprintf` implementation of the bundled C(++) RTL for x86 and x64 in conformance with the C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999), assuming

- `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is performed before `#include <stdio.h>`, which is required for modern versions of Visual Studio RTL;
- if `count` is greater than zero, then `buffer` is a pointer to (at least) `count` writable characters;
- format is not `NULL` and conforms to [Microsoft's Format Specification syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) as applicable to the particular version of the RTL;
- the value of `count` and the number of characters to produce are both small enough to fit type `int`;

and we want conformance to include (beside basic functionality for nominal input) these requirements (implied by the standard's specification of `snprintf`, which `vsnprintf` references):

1. not producing undefined behavior (including invoking [Microsoft's invalid parameter handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx)) under the above assumptions;
2. returning the length to be written (not including terminating null character) when `buffer==NULL` and `count==0`, thus allowing pre-flight to determine the length of the output;
3. always padding the output string with a terminating null character when `buffer!=NULL` and `count>0` and the result returned is non-negative, including for truncated output due to small `count`.

Note following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34996375/903600#comment57721538_34996375): I'm willing to admit the lack of `restrict` qualifiers as still within allowance for mostly standard-conformant.

---

The documentation leaves conformance ambiguous with respect to (3.); the implementation bundled with Visual Studio Community 2015 is fine as far as I can tell, but not all are.

> If there is room at the end (that is, if the number of characters to write is less than `count`), the buffer will be null-terminated.

The documentation also has wording unambiguously implying that `vsnprintf` is not in conformance with the C99 standard with respect to (1.) and (2.) when `buffer==NULL` and `count==0` ; but theses parts of the documentation seemingly turn out to be wrong:

> if the number of characters to write is greater than `count`, these functions return -1 indicating that output has been truncated.
>
> If `buffer` or `format` is `NULL`, or if `count` is less than or equal to zero, these functions invoke the invalid parameter handler

---

Test code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int f( char *buffer,
       size_t count,
       const char *format,
       ...
     )
{
    va_list vArgs;
    int vRes;
    va_start(vArgs, format);
    vRes = vsnprintf( buffer, count, format, vArgs);
    va_end(vArgs);
    return vRes;
}

int main(void)
{
    char vBuf[6];
    int j, count;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    printf("_MSC_VER = %ld\n",(long)(_MSC_VER));
#else
    printf("_MSC_VER is undefined\n");
#endif
    printf("f(NULL,0,\"%%d\",777):%3d\n", f(NULL,0,"%d",777));
    for(count=0 ;count<=sizeof(vBuf); ++count)
    {
        for(j=0; j<sizeof(vBuf)-1; ++j)
            vBuf[j] = '!';
        vBuf[j] = 0;
        j =  f(vBuf,count,"%d",777);
        printf("f(vBuf,%d,\"%%d\",777):%3d  vBuf: \"%s\"\n",count,j,vBuf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

giving under my install of Visual Studio Community 2015

```
_MSC_VER = 1900
f(NULL,0,"%d",777):  3
f(vBuf,0,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "!!!!!"
f(vBuf,1,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: ""
f(vBuf,2,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "7"
f(vBuf,3,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "77"
f(vBuf,4,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "777"
f(vBuf,5,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "777"
f(vBuf,6,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "777"
```

and under some install of Visual Studio 2008 (I believe SP1 + PSDK 7.1)

```
_MSC_VER = 1500
f(NULL,0,"%d",777):  3
f(vBuf,0,"%d",777): -1  vBuf: "!!!!!"
f(vBuf,1,"%d",777): -1  vBuf: "7!!!!"
f(vBuf,2,"%d",777): -1  vBuf: "77!!!"
f(vBuf,3,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "777!!"
f(vBuf,4,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "777"
f(vBuf,5,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "777"
f(vBuf,6,"%d",777):  3  vBuf: "777"
```

Notice the lack of terminating null character in particular for `count==3`, even though the output is positive.

Comment: That's not the prototype of vsnprintf.

Comment: From C11: `int vsnprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n,
const char * restrict format,
va_list arg);` Most notably the absence of restrict pointers already makes the function non-compliant.

Comment: I would say the VS2015 version looks more like the behaviour described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf): _"The resulting character string will be terminated with a null character, unless buf_size is zero."_ and _" If the resulting string gets truncated due to buf_size limit, function returns the total number of characters (not including the terminating null-byte) which would have been written, if the limit was not imposed."_ . Yet the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx) doesn't seem to be up-to-date if you look at the example...

Comment: I left out the part that states what shall happen for a nullptr buffer: "If buf_size is zero, nothing is written and buffer may be a null pointer, however the return value (number of bytes that would be written) is still calculated and returned.". I am not sure if this part is correctly applied in the VS2015 version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very page you mention now gives the answer:

> Beginning with the UCRT in Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10, vsnprintf is no longer identical to _vsnprintf. The vsnprintf function complies with the C99 standard; _vnsprintf is retained for backward compatibility with older Visual Studio code.

And your output is consistent with [_vsnprintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vsnprintf-vsnprintf-vsnprintf-l-vsnwprintf-vsnwprintf-l):

> Both _vsnprintf and _vsnwprintf functions return  the number of characters written if the number of  characters to write is less than or equal to count;  if the number of characters to write is greater than count, these functions return -1 indicating that output has been truncated.