# SDL_Log doesn't seem to support %g and %e specifiers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL 2.0.12 with Visual Studio 2013, and I'm seeing this:

```
SDL_Log("%f", 1.0); // fine
SDL_Log("%g", 1.0); // no luck; prints blank line
```

Do I need to switch to a newer/older version of SDL or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SDL_Log` delegates to `SDL_vsnprintf`. There are three possibilities:

```
#if defined(HAVE_LIBC) && defined(__WATCOMC__)
```

This seems to check for the Watcom C compiler. Not for you.

```
#elif defined(HAVE_VSNPRINTF)
```

This case delegates to your compiler's implementation of `vsnprintf` if that symbol was defined at compilation time. VS2015 appears to have the %g specifier, I assume VS2013 as well. You can check this yourself trivially.

```
#else
```

**I think you are in this situation.**
This uses a custom implementation in SDL. This indeed [lacks support for the %g modifier](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/a91ab883e970611cef0924df8aec7d264f93c8d1/src/stdlib/SDL_string.c#L1801-L1922), but you could add it yourself (and submit a pull request).

Comment: Thank you!  So this is a combo of the SDL folks taking naughty shortcuts with their own implementation (and then not documenting them), and also not trusting Microsoft's implementation of this method, seemingly with good reason somewhat recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996375/starting-at-what-version-of-visual-studio-is-vsnprintf-mostly-standard-conforman   Bu

Comment: seems like I was a bit wrong about SDL motivations... they try not to depend on the standard library on Windows at all apparently, because otherwise the user of SDL has to compile with same version of Visual Studio as the one used to compile SDL itself... or something like that